# DT columns shifting width changing when sorting

Tags: r, shiny, datatable, flexbox, dt

I am using a datatable inside a flexdashboard and am having alignment issues when sorting columns. When I sort by certain columns some of the values are longer than others which is causing the columns to resize and making the column headers become misaligned with the values.

I have tried several things such as `autoWidth=T`, setting the column width to a certain size with `width`, and centering the values in the columns with `className = 'dt-center'` but the issue is still persisting.

Comment: Consider adding a [mre] to the question. Doing so will help the community to provide a good answer.

Comment: In your `options` list you can specify the width of the columns. For example: `columnDefs = list(width = '100px', targets = c(1,3))`